# Clear cache on post of one type when something happens to post of other type

Tags: save-post, wp-update-post, customization

**EDIT:** *Based on @TimHallman's answer I have a follow-up question, please see the bottom of this post.*

I am trying to do something that is way over my head and the more I think of it, the more questions I end up with.

This is the scenario I have:

- Custom posts of type **golfcourse**, each presenting a golf course.
- Custom posts of type **clubnews**.
- *Clubnews* has the term **clubnewsowner** related to them.
- *The clubnewsowner taxonomies are identical to the golfcourses.*

What I do is that (using a self made shortcode) I check, on each golfcourse-post, if one or more posts of type clubnews with taxonomy related to the spesific golfcourse exists. If yes, show the clubnews-post(s) on the golfcourse-post.

This works as I want it to.

I do, however, use the WP-Rocket caching plugin on this website. And because the clubnews-posts are added (to the golfcourse-posts) using php only (no ajax), WP-Rocket has no clue the content has changed on the golfcourse-post whenever a clubnews post has been added, updated or deleted. This means that I need to do a manual cache-clearing of the related golfcourse-post whenever the mentioned scenario occurs.

Luckily, WP-Rocket has a function for this:

```
//clean post with ID 5
rocket_clean_post( 5 );
```

I have managed to create some kind of pseudo-code:

```
function clearPageCacheBasedOnTaxOfClubnews() {
    if ( ( clubnews is created ) || ( clubnews is updated )  || ( clubnews is deleted ) ) {

        $customPost = clubnewsPostID;

        // The result here is always only one taxonomy
        $taxonomyOfCustompPost = get_post_taxonomies( $customPost );

        switch ($taxonomyOfCustompPost) {
            case 'golfcourseOne': rocket_clean_post( 5 );
            break;
            case 'golfcourseTwo': rocket_clean_post( 8 );
            break;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'when?', 'clearPageCacheBasedOnTaxOfClubnews', 10, ?);
```

I think the above code will work, but there is a lot of things I am not sure of here:

1. How do I get the ID of the clubnews post being created/updated/deleted?
2. How do I check if it is actually being created/updated/deleted?
3. At this point my head starts spinning, and I am no longer sure what I am wondering...

ANY help is appreciated!

---

**Follow-up question:**

I do believe @Tim Hallman solves at least two thirds of this (I need another action for when a clubnews custom post gets deleted) with his answer below.

I, however cannot make this work. My code produces a white screen of death, whitout generating any php errors. What I think happens is that WP Rocket uses all of the resources on the server when clearing the cache on individual posts. I'm not sure though.

This is the code:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'clearPageCacheBasedOnTaxOfClubnews');


function clearPageCacheBasedOnTaxOfClubnews($post_id) {

    /* Is has_term() used correctly here? In the codex it says that the
     * taxonomy parameter is optional, other places on the Internet claims
     * the opposite...
     */
    if ( has_term('clubnewsowner', '', $post_id ) {

        // The result here is always only one taxonomy
        $taxonomyOfCustompPost = get_post_taxonomies( $post_id );

        /* The codex says get_post_taxonomies() returns an array. The code
         * on the line below produces a php fatal error though.
         */
        $taxonomyOfCustompPost = $taxonomyOfCustompPost[0];

        /* This is where the connection between the taxonomy of the
         * Clubnews custom posts and the golf course pages happens
         */
        switch ($taxonomyOfCustompPost){
            case 'Course One': $courseID = 123; break;
            case 'Course Two': $courseID = 234; break;
            case 'Course Three': $courseID = 345; break;
            ...
        }

        //This cleans the cache of the selected post
        rocket_clean_post( $courseID );
    }
}
```

I have tried this in different variants, and either I get a fatal error because of the $taxonomyOfCustompPost = taxonomyOfCustompPost[0]; or I get a white screen of death whitout any php errors at all.

Any suggestions on where to go on from here?

Comment: you probably want the `save_post` hook

Comment: Thank you @TimHallman. But that doesnt cover all three scenarios, does it? (New, updated or deleted.) Maybe I will have to add three actions...

Comment: Check out the CODEX: "save_post is an action triggered whenever a post or page is created or updated" https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Comment: please don't ask additional question, if you have a different question, even if related, just ask it as a new question.

Comment: Ah, @MarkKaplun! Glad you are still here! Imagine the server has limited resources. Imagine WP Rocket, due to my bad coding (like when $courseID has no value in rocket_clean_post( $courseID ); so it clears the cache individually on every post on the site, putting the server to halt for a while). Where, exactly, would you suggest this error shows?

Comment: Just to clearify: My above comment was made because @MarkKaplun politely pointed out that WSOD Always produces a php error. Then, for some reason, when I asked the follow-up question, he edited his comment. I ask you Kaplun, since you seem to know your way around here, if this is the correct way to do it? (I felt so stupid when my comment suddenly seemed so out of context...)

Comment: This is not a problem, I just reread your question and saw that you indicate you already solved some so decided to edit it out of my comment. The only thing that might result in WSOD without an error is if PHP times out, which might happen if you have a recursion, although I would still expect some (maybe not very useful) log entry. Other things "load" related like consuming too much memory should definitely have log entry.

Comment: some general comments about your code. 1. It probably runs when drafts are saved, and you most likely do not want it, so check the status of the post before doing anything. 2. You should probably check if the action is triggered by wp_rocket, for whatever reason, and if so implement so protection a against it (static variable holing ids of processed posts for example). 3. Never trust default values, always specify them, especially when you use unfamiliar APIs. 4. Hardcoding post IDs is a general no-no.

Comment: 5. Don't trust what the codex says, most wordpress APIs can return a `WP_Error` object. If you feel like something funky is going on, carefully inspect the errors, and var_dump the returned values

Comment: and always develop with `WP_DEBUG` set to true and use the query monitor plugin

Comment: If your WSOD is happening right off then it's probably not timing out. You'd likely see a 500 error or something. I'll update my answer with some debugging methods to help you out @erolha

Comment: @TimHallman Thanks, but there is no instant need. I'm pretty sure I know what happens and it is either related to get_post_taxonomies() or has_term(). It is, however, friday night here, and I won't be able to relate to this for some time.

Comment: Okay, check my updated answer though, it may help debug your WSOD

Comment: @TimHallman Thanks, I appreciate it. But know that this is of course already in place (how else could I see the error messages related to  $taxonomyOfCustompPost = taxonomyOfCustompPost[0];?). No worries though, I will return here with the (potential) progress, and in the end, if I figure this out, I will still accept your initial answer. I do believe it's correct. I just think my interpretation of it is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose a quick and dirty way to achieve what you want is to clear the entire site cache, something like this:

```
function clear_rocket_cache_on_post_save() {
     rocket_clean_domain();
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'clear_rocket_cache_on_post_save' );
```

Otherwise you'll need to do a query to get the matching post, something like this should work:

```
  function clear_rocket_cache_on_post_save( $post_id ) {

       // $result_id = tax query by $post_id
       rocket_clean_post( $result_id );

  }
  add_action( 'save_post', 'clear_rocket_cache_on_post_save' );
```

You can find more information on Wordpress's "out of the box" caching features here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

and here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache

Many themes do not utilize this core functionality, but it's there.

UPDATE:

If you're not getting debugging output on your screen, the best way to figure out why you're getting errors is to use the debug.log.

First, put this snippet at the bottom of your `functions.php` file.

```
if (!function_exists('write_log')) {
    function write_log ( $log )  {
        if ( true === WP_DEBUG ) {
            if ( is_array( $log ) || is_object( $log ) ) {
                error_log( print_r( $log, true ) );
            } else {
                error_log( $log );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then edit your `wp-config.php` file to include these:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Then in your `wp-content` folder create a new file called `debug.log`. Now you are ready to debug.

Now whatever you want to output you use the function `write_log($some_variable)` and it'll output your debugging errors to `debug.log`. Do that and I bet you'll see why you're getting a WSOD. /happy coding

Comment: Ah, could it be that simple? And include a "check if $post_id has the term clubnews connected. If yes, do the switch." I'll give it a shot and get back here with the results. Thanks!

Comment: @erolha please accept this answer if this worked for you. Disregard the other guy. Wordpress does have page caching "out of the box", it's built into the core of Wordpress and the WP devs spent a lot of time doing that. Have a look at `transients`

Comment: Also see here. WP has tons of caching features built into the core "out of the box". Just because some themes don't leverage it doesn't mean it's not there. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache

Comment: your answer is probably the correct one, and as soon as I stop getting white screen of death because of my erroneous code I will take actions here. I have been struggling with figuring out if my questions now belong in a new thread or if I should  continue here. I'll update my question now with the code not working...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got this working. The solution is based on @TimHallman' answer below/above here.

One of the reasons I didn't get it to work was I was confused with what is a term and what is a taxonomy. I thought a term *contained* taxonomies when it is the opposite....

Despite good advices of not hardcoding stuff like this, not caching dynamic sites and so on there are scenarios when code like this is needed. And here is the working code:

```
// Run the function when a post is created or updated
add_action( 'save_post', 'clearPageCacheBasedOnTaxOfClubnews');
function clearPageCacheBasedOnTaxOfClubnews($post_id) {

    $taxonomyOfCustompPost = get_post_taxonomies( $post_id );
    // In this special case, there is always only one taxonomy!
    $taxCustompPost = $taxonomyOfCustompPost[0];

    if ( $taxCustompPost != 'clubnewsowner' ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $taxCustompPost == 'clubnewsowner' ) {
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'clubnewsowner', array("fields" => "names"));
        $term = $terms[0];;

        switch ($term){
            case 'Course One': $courseID = 123; break;
            case 'Course Two': $courseID = 456; break;
            case 'Course Three': $courseID = 789; break;
            ...
        }

        rocket_clean_post( $courseID );


    }
}

//Run the function when the post is deleted
add_action('trash_post','clearPageCacheWhenCPDeleted',1,1);
function clearPageCacheWhenCPDeleted($post_id){

    if(!did_action('trash_post')){

        $taxonomyOfCustompPost = get_post_taxonomies( $post_id );
        // In this special case, there is always only one taxonomy!
        $taxCustompPost = $taxonomyOfCustompPost[0];

        if ( $taxCustompPost != 'clubnewsowner' ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( $taxCustompPost == 'clubnewsowner' ) {

            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'clubnewsowner', array("fields" => "names"));
            $term = $terms[0];;

            switch ($term){
                case 'Course One': $courseID = 123; break;
                case 'Course Two': $courseID = 456; break;
                case 'Course Three': $courseID = 789; break;
            }

            rocket_clean_post( $courseID );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "When deleted" hook is also based on this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/44460

Comment: yeh hardcoding is very bad here. someone changes the name of the course and things stop working

Comment: @markkaplun In general, you are of course right. In this case though, you are wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, once you start using page caching you can not do dynamic things. This is part of why wordpress do not have page caching out of the box.

Cleaning up a page cache, especially when it is not on the server wordpress runs on, can be a long process which will make your server busier (and the whole point of having a page cache is to reduce the load).

From your description, the problem you are facing is not a real problem, as no one will die from having some stale gulf course information, but if you just have to have it, the easier way is to reduce the time until the cache expires. This will be easier to do and you will not need to write code which is likely to have bugs and will need constant maintenance.

Comment: Wordpress does have caching out of the box. Look at transients.

Comment: Well, one reason to do this is that it is not I who post the clubnews. Imagine a scenario where you have a couple of hundred authors publishing without seeing their posts being published instantly. Sorry for describing the issue in such a way that it appears not to be a problem...

Comment: @TimHallman, I advice to read again what I wrote. And wordpress has zero caching out of the box

Comment: I'm not going to get into a flinging match, you said "This is part of why wordpress do not have page caching out of the box." That is not true. Furthermore, to suggest his problem is not real is also incorrect.

Comment: @erolha, logged in users should not be served content from cache. In addition, the more content you have the longer it will take to clear the associated content as there will be more of it, and you will have to do it more times as with more authors there is likely to be more frequent updates.

Comment: well @TimHallman, maybe it is time you started to learn about how wordpress caching works. No matter what is out job title, there are always things we do not know

Comment: @MarkKaplun In my case logged in users SHOULD be served content from cache. But this is outside my question.

Comment: Than @erolha, you are doing it wrong, or at least you should serve that part of the content as ajax only to those users.

Comment: I know how Wordpress caching works, thank you. Solution already posted. Perhaps you need to learn how it works. Caching is an integral part of the Wordpress core.

Comment: @TimHallman if you keep believing that wordpress has any kind of caching which lives  longer then a session then you don't know.

Comment: You are wrong and clearly don't know the differences between caching and serving static html files. https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

Comment: seriously @TimHallman, you are welcome to "the loop" chat as this is totally not the place for a discussion. Calling transients "cache" is like calling every DB write a cache, which is true in a way, but core do not use even such a primitive construct in any meaningful way that might be related to performance improvement. Core believes in being dynamic and leave caching to plugins.